# Is the pronoun 'it' used correctly in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns, antecedents, it-its-itself

I have come across a sentence in which the pronoun 'it' occurs but seems to have no antecedent, and I think it should be omitted:

> - *A controlling idea: what the writer is going to focus on it in the paragraph.*

For more context, here is the page of the school English textbook from which I quoted.
[image: A page taken from a school English Textbook]

Comment: I don't know what it is called formally, but it is effectively doubling up the object with the "what" and the "it". "The writer is going to focus on it" is ok on its own. Or you could move "it" to the start, as "it is what the writer is going to focus on". In your construction you have done this and replaced the opening "it" by the part leading up to the colon. Having moved it and then taken it out, it is wrong to put it back where it came from.

Comment: There is no sentence involved, but rather two fragments separated by a colon. The second fragment is very probably an expansive / explicatory appositive. If this is the case, the 'it' is certainly an error and a rewrite is _A controlling idea – ie what the writer is going to focus on in the paragraph._ //// However, colons introduce other types of  expressions of further information. Consider _John: what he did in the holidays_.  It is possible though unlikely ...

Comment: that  _A controlling idea: What the writer is going to focus on it in the paragraph_ has 'A controlling idea' as antecedent for 'it' just as 'John' is the antecedent for 'he'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pronoun *it* in the sentence

> A controlling idea: What the writer is going to focus on **it** in the paragraph.

is unnecessary and ungrammatical.

Such pronouns, which are usually but not always in a relative clause, are called *resumptive* pronouns. This is a grammatical feature of some languages, but not English.

An exception in English is the informal resumptive pronoun in statements such as following, with the resumptive *it*:

> This virus, it's such a tragedy.

Your sentence should be rewritten without the pronoun as:

> A controlling idea: What the writer is going to focus on in the paragraph.

Alternatively:

> A controlling idea is what the writer is going to focus on in the paragraph.

Wikipedia has this on [resumptive pronouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resumptive_pronoun) in English and other languages.

Comment: I have added the main source of the sentece. You can check it if you want to.

Comment: @Ata. Thanks for adding the source. It is common to use the colon in this kind of sentence to separate a word from its definition or explanation. In the same way that sentence 1 (_'Topic: what the paragraph is about __it___') would be ungrammatical, I regard sentence 2 as also ungrammatical.

Comment: Yeah, it's an editing typo. Easy to do when you're writing and changing your mind; little words can get missed and left behind for readers to trip over. And by the way, this should give you an idea how much care and knowledge was expended on this textbook. Throw it away.

Comment: @Greybeard "[T]he *it* should NOT be omitted"? Is that a typo?